# Multi-directional angularjs view animation

Tags: angularjs, css, animation, angular-ui-router, ng-animate

**The goal:** A multi-directional horizontal slide animation between angularjs views that slides left or right depending on the order of navigation.

**The problem:** I can't find a good way to let the view know that I am going a specific direction that actually works.

**What I've got so far:**
See [this codepen](http://codepen.io/Reklino/pen/KpqooK).
I'm applying the `back` class to the body if we're going backwards in navigation based on the order of the objects in the navigation. I use this class to tell the view to animate inversely if necessary.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    $scope.back = toParams.id < fromParams.id ? true : false;
});
```

**Why I don't think it's working:** The 'back' class isn't being applied to the newly inserted 'ui-view' element, so it is not obeying the css.

Anyone got any ideas? Feel free to fork to codepen...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a workaround and not the right way to do this.
What i did was re apply the class . I noticed the animation only happens when the `back` class is switched . So on state-change start i swapped the `back` class and re applied it.

```
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
       $scope.back = $scope.back ? false : true;
       $timeout( function(){        
           $scope.back = toParams.id < fromParams.id ? true : false;
       }, 1);       
});
```

Here is the [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJwzVP).